# Decompose $\mathbb {Z}_{pq}^* / (\mathbb {Z}_{pq}^*)^2$ into a direct sum of cyclic groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> Let $\mathbb {Z}_{pq}^*$ be the set of all units of $\mathbb {Z}_{pq}$ and $(\mathbb {Z}_{pq}^*)^2 = \{ a^2 \mid a \in \mathbb {Z}_{pq} \}$. ($p, q$ are distinct odd primes.) Decompose $\mathbb {Z}_{pq}^* / (\mathbb {Z}_{pq}^*)^2$ into a direct sum of cyclic groups.

My strategy is the following.

1. To show that the orders of $\mathbb {Z}_{pq}^*$ and $(\mathbb {Z}_{pq}^*)^2$ are $(p-1)(q-1)$ and $(p-1)(q-1)/4$ respectively.
2. Then $\mathbb {Z}_{pq}^* / (\mathbb {Z}_{pq}^*)^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb {Z}_4$ or $\mathbb {Z}_2 \times \mathbb {Z}_2$. So it needs to investigate order of elements.

I couldn't solve even the first one. I want to get a proof or some hints. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, there is a ring isomorphism

$$
\mathbb{Z} / pq\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / q\mathbb{Z}
$$

This gives rise to an isomorphism 
$$\mathbb{Z}_{pq}^{*} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q}^{*}$$

This then induces 
$$(\mathbb{Z}_{pq}^{*})^2 \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*})^2 \times (\mathbb{Z}_{q}^{*})^2$$

And then using the fact that $\mathbb{Z}_p^{*}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_q^{*}$ are cyclic it is easy to see:

$$\mathbb{Z}_{pq}^{*} / (\mathbb{Z}_{pq}^{*})^2 \cong \mathbb{Z}_p^{*} / (\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*})^2 \times \mathbb{Z}_q^{*} / (\mathbb{Z}_{q}^{*})^2 \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$$